# Rails4 drop down boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a new task through this form. But it says

> **Invalid single-table inheritance type: hot is not a subclass of Task**

Here are my codes. The problem must be relevant to the "f.select" in new.html.erb

```
 def new 
   @task = Task.new
 end

 def create
       @task = Task.new(task_params)
       if @task.save
       # Handle a successful save.
       flash[:success] = "Task accepted!"
       redirect_to @task
       else
       render 'new'
       end
 end

private
      def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:type, :title, :details,:url)
end
```

And new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>


      <%= f.label :Select_Type %>
      <%= f.select :type, [['Hot','hot'],['Medium','medium'],['Cold','cold']] %>


      <%= f.label :Title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>

      <%= f.label :Details %>
      <%= f.text_field :details %>

      <%= f.label :Your_file_location %>
      <%= f.text_field :url %>

      <%= f.submit "Create a New Task", class: "btn, btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is "type". I have no idea to solve this problem. I tried everything i can find in Stackoverflow, but I got the same error. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your table like? Do you have a type column in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at rails guide [Schema Convensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions), you can see that `type` is a reserved column for STI (Single table inheritance). You need to rename your column or tell rails model to use different column for STI. You can find more about STI in [official docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)